# Electron database handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am trying to write a small app with Electron that needs a database. Currently I'm testing PouchDB, but that shouldn't really matter.
For better code quality I created a class that is going to handle the common database requests - it should be the only way to access the db.

Not sure, if I understood the main/renderer process concept correctly, but I think the main process should take care about db access. So this is my current configuration:

**main.js**

```
import Database from './database'
export const myDB = new Database()
```

**database.js** (obviously only a stub)

```
export default class Database {
  hello = () => {
    console.log("Hello World")
  }
}
```

**Root.js** (one of the ui components [using react])

```
const remote = require('electron').remote
const main = remote.require('./main.js')
...
<button onClick={() => main.myDB.hello()}>Test</button>
```

**My question**: Is this a feasible solution for code structuring or am I getting something completely wrong? My JS experiences are just using some jQuery effects and Node experience is missing completely. This is just a small hobby project, so I just wanted to start coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have it at the right end, the database related code should be executed in the main process.

main.js is what would be the main process, but it seems to be missing the code that creates a browser window (which in turn creates the renderer process). Take a look at the example of Electron [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md), the magic happens at createWindow().

Root.js is executed in the renderer process, it can only communicate with the main process through 'remote' or 'ipcRenderer' - the latter being a bit more secure. A bit more information about remote can be found [on electron.rocks](http://electron.rocks/different-ways-to-communicate-between-main-and-renderer-process/). You are doing it the right way, in terms of code structure.

> The main process is responsible for creating and managing BrowserWindow instances and various application events. It can also do things like register global shortcuts, create native menus and dialogs, respond to auto-update events, and more. Your app’s entry point will point to a JavaScript file that will be executed in the main process. A subset of Electron APIs (see graphic below) are available in the main process, as well as all node.js modules. The docs state: “The basic rule is: if a module is GUI or low-level system related, then it should be only available in the main process.”

^Quoted from somewhere